# sbt resources not copied

Tags: resources, sbt

It appears as though sbt (1.2.1, 1.2.3) is not copying resource files (from `src/main/resources`) to the target directory.

The build is multi-project, with a root project that aggregates `subprj1` (for now).

Showing below: project structure (main directories and one resource file: `application.conf`), the `resourceDirectory` as proof that we have not overridden it, proof of successful compilation - and yet the `application.conf` file has not been copied to the output (`target`) directory.

Tried sbt versions 1.2.1, 1.2.3.

Why are the resources not being copied to the output, since we are complying with the standard directory structure?

Project structure

```
/main/project/home/dir/build.sbt
/main/project/home/dir/subprj1/src/main/resources
/main/project/home/dir/subprj1/src/main/resources/application.conf
/main/project/home/dir/subprj1/src/main/scala/com/myco/foo/bar/server/*.scala

IJ][subprj1@master] λ show resourceDirectory 
[info] subprj1 / Compile / resourceDirectory
[info]  /main/project/home/dir/subprj1/src/main/resources

build/sbt clean compile
...
[success] Total time: 22 s, completed Feb 8, 2019 3:10:04 PM

find . -name application.conf
./subprj1/src/main/resources/application.conf
```

It works if we run `copyResources` after `compile`, but why is that not automatic?

```
build/sbt copyResources
find . -name application.conf
./subprj1/src/main/resources/application.conf
./subprj1/target/scala-2.12/classes/application.conf
```

I can inspect the dependencies among tasks and I can see that `compile` does not depend on `copyResources`, but was it always like this, or is this a recent change? I have been using sbt for years, and I have this expectation that the build would copy resources to output automatically.

`build/sbt -Dsbt.log.noformat=true "inspect tree compile" > t.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out someone had added the settings below to `build.sbt`. Once I commented out these lines, the resources started being copied to the output directory.

`, unmanagedResourceDirectories in Compile := Seq()
 , unmanagedResourceDirectories in Test := Seq()`